# Convert html img tag to css

Tags: html, css, image

How do I convert and img tag to css so I don't have to have a million img tags. Or whats the best way todo images with css

`<img src="hg-rx.gif" name="foo" width="18" height="18">`

I tried background:url in css and it needs text for it to display properly, id hilight and the image would disappear

```
.hg-text-rx {
  background:url(hg-rx.gif);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
 }
```

Comment: Can't really *convert* an image tag into css...

Comment: `img` elements are supposed to be semantic markup. If you had previously used them for structural markup, and are now moving to using CSS: congratulations!

Comment: @zzzzBov - but if he is replacing actual content images with CSS, then that is not a good thing.

Comment: What @Charles says. For actual content, this has several massive downsides outlined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492809/when-to-use-img-vs-css-background-image) - most prominently, browsers won't print them any more. There is nothing wrong with having a million `img` tags if you have a million actual images

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with just css by using a div or other block element of fixed width and height and make the image the background of that. But to do this, you must still put the div (for the image) in the HTML so you aren't really cleaning anything up, unless you are just trying to make the site easier to skin completely using CSS. However, this does make rollover states a breeze.

```
div#hg-rx {
display:block;
width:18px;
height:18px;
background: url(hg-rx.gif) 0 0 no-repeat transparent;
}

<div id="hg-rx"></div>
```

If you are doing borders, rounded corners or buttons you might want to look into sprites. 
http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Answer (score 0):

you can add a image as background in css, but you must set the `width` and `height` of image to be visible.

**css**

```
.hg-text-rx {background:url("http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/545");width:200px;height:200px};
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/2XX8A/

Answer (score 0):

Actually, while this cannot be done strictly in CSS, if you have `IMG` tags and want to convert them to divs, you can do so using jQuery (a javascript wrapper) **on the fly** pretty easily.

**LIVE DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/Epgvc/4/

**HTML**

```
<img src='http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff&text=image1' />
<img src='http://dummyimage.com/100x100/f00/ff0&text=image2' />
<img src='http://dummyimage.com/250x50/0ff/fff&text=image3' />
```

**JS**

```
$('img').each(function(){
    var html="<div style='border:1px solid #ff0;width:" + $(this).width() + "px;height:" + $(this).height() + "px;background:url(" + $(this).attr('src')+ ");color:#fff;'>This is a Div!</div>"
    $(html).insertBefore($(this));
    $(this).remove(); //Comment out this line if you want to leave the original image
});
```

Comment: I couldn't see a JavaScript tag, let alone a jQuery one..?

Comment: Well, if he's talking about actually "Converting" images to divs using CSS, then this is the way to do it. Perhaps the question is poorly phrased and I should be more clear in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you intent on having the image as a background to a text field you could alway use text-indent

```
.hg-text-rx {
  background:url(hg-rx.gif);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
**text-indent:-10000px;**
 }
```

`<p>`this text wont show, but the image will`</p>`

However there is conflicting arguments about this technique from a seo point of view