# how to make an image act as a link w/o javascript

Tags: xhtml, tags, hyperlink, image

what is the best solution to having a link have both text and and image, and the solution will still be w3c validated under XHTML 1.0 STRICT?  And w/o javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS, no need for javascript in the first place.

```
<a href="#" class="image">Hello</a>

<style>
    .image {
       padding-left: 20px; // width of image
       background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat scroll left center;
       height: 20px; // height of image
       line-height: 20px; //height of image
       // other rules that you need  
    }
</style>
```

Comment: actually, i really like yours.  It's clear and no html.  As a matter of fact, the image in this case is just for "style" and decoration.  Great solution!

Comment: Honestly, this is a super great solution, shows the power of css and fully xhtml 1.0 strict validated, and i've been trying to figure a work around with this for a while lol..thanks.

Comment: :) css is very powerfull indeed, all you need to do is find your way around it and get creative. as i see your new around here, you can mark one of the answers as accepted if your satisfied with it, there's a tick icon below the upvote-downvote option on the left :P

Comment: This is technically not semantically correct, as the image isn't a background image, but an inline image, and so corroded's solution is actually correct.

Comment: no your incorrect, i don't care if the image itself has behavior, i just need it to appear as if it's "clickable".

Comment: @mc10 technically semantically correct? i've been working in the field for about 4/5 years and i can't understand that, care to explain?

Comment: It depends, but usually, if the image is has an important semantic meaning within the page itself, using an image provides the best compatibility between users. See also: [When to use IMG vs. CSS background-image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492809/when-to-use-img-vs-css-background-image)

Comment: It's a link really. When someone wants an image and a text it's usually an icon / small image, but you want to have the link and link text, that's important. You wouldn't ask for a link on a 1000sq px and 4 words, would you? And by the way, I was being ironic, I know what you meant, I just think you're using words that you don't really understand. COmpatibility between users? Seriously, I don't just post stuff for fun.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried reading through http://htmldog.com/? That usually shows how to use basic HTML

```
<a href="link.html">
  TEXT HERE
  <img src="imageurl.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="TEXT HERE FOR ALT" />
</a>
```

Comment: @mc10 i have been enlightened!

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap the link (anchor) around a div, and [give the div a background image](http://www.w3.org/WAI/UA/TS/html401/cp0301/0301-CSS-DIV-BACKGROUND-IMAGE.html) w CSS.  The within the DIV add a span containing the text and set "margin" style on the span to align the text to taste.

Essentially test TEXT will look superimposed on the image.

Hope this helps.