# Should we always try to use maximum images in CSS sprite to reduce http request?

Tags: html, css, accessibility, semantics, pagespeed

For example

I need to place some logos on a Web page

[image]

Should I use all logos as a `backgroud-image` (CSS Sprite) and keep logot text in mark-up (But hidden through css)

or I should use `<img src="" alt="" width="" height="">` for each

Comment: You can find a question very similar to yours here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492809/when-to-use-img-vs-css-background-image

Comment: @Gaurav Gupta - Thanks +1 . Really useful and related discussion

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps for image search results? Even with the logo text hidden in the background, the image itself won't be found.