# Is using <img> for a menu item wrong?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, image

```
<div class="dashboard-icon">
        <a href="./structure/">
        <img class="admin-icon" src="<?=inc_path;?>images/icons/home.png" alt="" /></a><br />
        <p>Dashboard</p>
</div>
```

This is part of a menu, do you think it would be better in a UL > LI? I want a label underneath the icon.

Trying to think of reasons if this is bad or not. :)

Comment: Possibly related: [When to use IMG vs. CSS background-image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492809/when-to-use-img-vs-css-background-image)

Comment: Something that is not necessarily wrong but is probably not required is the `<br />` after the `</a>`. Since it is followed by a `<p>` the line break is implicit, and if you want to bring the `<p>` down a bit from the image, give it a `margin-top:`...

Comment: One of the problem you might have, is that only image is a link, and text is not. If for some reason image fails to load, user will not be able to navigate your menu.(some modern browsers like FF5/6 don't display "broken image" image any more, they just hide image all together)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is using `<img>` for a menu item wrong?

Not if it is a content image (e.g. an icon).

> This is part of a menu, do you think it would be better in a UL > LI?

Menus are, typically, lists of links, and using `<ul>` and `<li>` would be appropriate. That won't prevent you from using an `<img>` though.

> `<p>Dashboard</p>`

A text description for an image probably doesn't deserve its own paragraph though. I'd set `display: block` on the image if I wanted to force a line break, and put the text inside the `<a>` so the entire thing is clickable. I certainly wouldn't use a line break **and** a paragraph. Use `margin` for spacing.