# set up img in the header of my website

Tags: css, html

I'm building a web site and I'm using HTML5. I'd insert into my header an img that is my company's logo. In terms of efficient and correctness it is better set up css propriety as `background-image: url("logo.gif")` in my css style or including in the html file

```
<header>
   <img src="logo.gif" alt="logo" />
</header>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is best to include the image as an `img` tag, not a `background-image`.

This means that if the client has disabled CSS on their browser, or it doesn't support CSS, they will still be able to see the logo at the top of the page.

---

This would also mean you could make the logo a link to the home page, which has become a general usability point for websites these days:

```
<header>
   <a href="/index.html"><img src="logo.gif" alt="logo" /></a>
</header>
```

For more information on this sort of situation, see this popular StackOverflow post:

[When to use IMG vs. CSS background-image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492809/when-to-use-img-vs-css-background-image)

Answer (score 3):

that depends.

If your logo should be clickable then include it in the HMTL. (usebility)

If it is only present for design purposes go with the CSS.

It is generally a better idea to define everything related to the appearance of the Website in the CSS.

html:

```
<header>
     <div id="company_logo"></div>
</header>
```

css:

```
#company_logo{
width:50px;
height:50px;
background-image:url();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to have some contents over your logo, I'd go for the `<img>` tag (it is also screen reader-friendly provided you have the "alt" text).

Answer (score 0):

Background images can not be printed, if your site has the purpose of being printed, then your logo won't display.

Remember that a logo is a content, and a background is a style. Using a background as a logo is not semantic.