# Using alt tags with div for SEO reasons?

Tags: html, css, seo

At the moment I'm using div's and 'background-image' in css to put in my images. However, how do I use these to my advantage regarding SEO? I used to use alt-tags a lot as part of my SEO strategy. How do you do this with div's. Or do you recommend just using img src in relevant parts?

Answer (score 5):

> At the moment I'm using div's and 'background-image' in css to put in my images.

Do that for background images. Don't do that for content images.

> However, how do I use these to my advantage regarding SEO?

Write (accessible) content for people. Trust search engines to find it.

> I used to use alt-tags a lot as part of my SEO strategy.

Hopefully they are [good alt texts](http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/alt/alt-text.html) (and hopefully you mean *attributes*, not tags).

> Or do you guys recommend just using img src in relevant parts?

Content images should use `<img>` elements.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the context.

If your image is a background image (as in a tiled background, or some form of image which belongs in the background), then it should be a background image, and in theory no alt text should be required.

If your image is a content image, then for accessibility & SEO purposes, this should be an `img` element.

Theres already quite a popular question on StackOverflow regarding the use of "img vs background-image" which can be found here:

[When to use IMG vs. CSS background-image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492809/when-to-use-img-vs-css-background-image)

Answer (score 1):

If the image is just for design reasons, add it via css's background-image and no alt for seo is needed. But when the image is important for the website's content, you should insert it inside the html and then use `<img src="" alt="" />`.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that doesn't follow [the HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.4) is a bad idea. Technically you can use title tags instead, but please, just don't.

Over optimizing in SEO is always a bad idea.