# how to use rails asset pipeline image in emberjs?

Tags: ember.js, asset-pipeline

I am using ember with rails. I want to get image path in rails asset pipeline. 
Does emberjs has any function like asset-path in sass-rails?

Comment: I know I can use *.handlebar.erb template, and use <img src="<%=asset_path('logo.png')%>">. But I wonder if there are better way.

Comment: curious if you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is hardly ideal, but for lack of a better solution I've been handling this in my css:

```
.logo{
   background-image: url(image_path('logo.png'))
 }
```

This approach is often fine, but it has drawbacks. There's an excellent Stackoverflow discussion of using img tags vs background-image [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492809/when-to-use-img-vs-css-background-image).