# Faster way of using images

Tags: html

I have an image that is loaded 100 times in a single page load in 100 divs,for example:

```
<div> 
  <img src="same.jpg">
</div>
.
.
.
.
<div> 
  <img src="same.jpg">
</div>
```

Is there any efficient way to optimize image load or load once and use as many times as wanted? Is using CSS "background-image" instead more faster?

Comment: The image should only load once now...  once it's downloaded, it will remain in the cache and not need to be downloaded 100 times.

Comment: Actually, after loading a new image, image will not be reloaded when insert the same image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser caches the image so it does not load it hundreds of times. Here is an extensive comparison between both: [When to use IMG vs. CSS background-image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492809/when-to-use-img-vs-css-background-image)

Answer (score 0):

The image will only be loaded once by the browser. The browser realises that these URLs all point to the same image, it's not going to go out and download it 100 times. See the network tab of your browser's developer tools to confirm this.