# how to arrange divs having images in a horizontal line

Tags: html, css

I have the following html..

```
<div class="container animate" data-animation="pulse">
    <div class="margin30 "></div>
    <h2 class="border-title">Powering payments for <span></span></h2>
    <div class="margin25"></div>
    <div style="display:table-cell;">
        <div>
            <img src="images/clientlogos/pappa.png" title="" width="170" height="88" style="margin-left:5px;">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="images/clientlogos/offergrid.png" title="" width="215" height="55" style="margin-left:5px;">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="images/clientlogos/index.png" title="" width="121" height="33" style="margin-left:5px;">
        </div>
        <div>  
            <img src="images/clientlogos/fudr.png" title="" width="156" height="65" style="margin-left:5px;">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="images/clientlogos/inloc8.png" title="" width="139" height="39" style="margin-left:5px;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone tell how could I arrange all the divs having images in a horizontal line.I want all the images in one line

Comment: use float:left Because Div is a block element or replace div by span

Comment: You mean like this: http://jsfiddle.net/xS2yw/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`float: left` on your divs is one option:

http://jsfiddle.net/c3DV3/

Comment: your fiddle,that is what i want.to give the css in the html itself,where can i place your css style in this html.can you tell me?Like <div style"float: left;"> this way,but for,images should i have to give the style for each image tags?

Comment: No way! You should create a separate style sheet (`.css` file) and include this one in your html head. A good source for HTML/CSS are the specifications: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/styles.html

Comment: HTML 4 Specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/
CSS 2 Specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/
For basic stuff, these are good resources, since HTML5/CSS3 is far from having good support among browsers. Have fun. :)

Comment: I have given   .client { float:left; display:inline-block; }
  .client img {
      border: 2px solid red;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      display: inline-block;
} 
in css,and add "client " to all divs.but its not working :( Can you help me out

Comment: Do you have a JSFiddle to sketch your problem?

Answer (score 3):

```
div, img {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only storing images in your div, you should check if it's better for you to use the `<img>` tag or to set them as a `background-image`, as stated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492809/when-to-use-img-vs-css-background-image). It mainly depends on what you are going to do with those images. Check the link for further informations.

Floating the divs on left like others already said is the proper way to do it. You could also use `display:inline-block;` (even if divs are rendered as blocks by default).

Personally I didn't get if you wanted just to display them on one line, or to align them on top: in this case, you can use `vertical-align:top;` in addition to the other CSS parameters to achieve the result.

Comment: I just want that images tobe aligned

Comment: Ok, assign a class to those divs `<div class="myClass">`, then in CSS write something like `.myClass { float:left; display:inline-block; }`, and it should work.

Comment: should i give all the images in a single <div> <img..> </img> <img>..</img> </div> will it work?