# standard for loading rails image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, sass

What is the best practise is for loading images in a rails app, for small things such as logo image.

should I load it through the rails image tag such as -

```
 <%= image_tag('logo.png', :size => '100x17') %>
```

or through css targeting an empty div such as -

```
 #logo{
    background: image-url('logo.png');
    width: 100px;
    height: 17px;
    margin-top: 15px;
 }
```

In this circumstance I would go for the rails image tag as it only requires one line of code where the latter requires more lines of code and an empty div.

Comment: Atleast accept/upvote/downvote any of the answers or delete your question if you are not satisfied by the answers available.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about Rails for a second and think *how you want your markup to look like*. Actually this is not a Rails-related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/492834/1242778

If you decide you want to do it with an `<img>` tag you can use the `image_tag` helper. Otherwise, your alternative is totally fine.

Answer (score 0):

The `image_tag` is rails default helper method for loading the images in your application. It comes with various options inside the tags and the syntax is as follows;

```
 image_tag(source, options = {}) public
```

Options

You can add HTML attributes using the options. The options supports three additional keys for convenience and conformance:

- `:alt` - If no alt text is given, the file name part of the source is
  used (capitalized and without the extension)
- `:size` - Supplied as “{Width}x{Height}”, so “30x45” becomes width=“30”
  and height=“45”. :size will be ignored if the value is not    in the
  correct format.
- `:mouseover` - Set an alternate image to be used when the onmouseover
  event is fired, and sets the original image to be    replaced
  onmouseout. This can be used to implement an easy image    toggle
  that fires on onmouseover.

These are the options which comes with it by default and no worries to write and extra css as you have asked and explained using css example as;

```
image_tag(source, options = {}) public
```

Returns an html image tag for the source. The source can be a full path or a file that exists in your public images directory

**Examples**

1st

`image_tag("icon.png", :size => "16x10", :alt => "Edit Entry")`

HTML Output

`<img src="/images/icon.png" width="16" height="10" alt="Edit Entry" />`

2nd

```
image_tag("mouse.png", :mouseover => image_path("mouse_over.png"))
```

HTML Output

`<img src="/images/mouse.png" onmouseover="this.src='/images/mouse_over.png'" onmouseout="this.src='/images/mouse.png'" alt="Mouse" />`

Hope this helps! :-)

Comment: for more you can refer http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag