# <img> element vs background-image

Tags: html, css, image

What are the other CSS definitions happening here that constrain the `<img>` element?

Here is an example, I'm only defining width and height, but you will see that the  element uses the entirety of the image and scales it to fit, while the `<div>` element uses the image at 100% scale and clips around the width and height.

How can I control the `<img>` to behave more like the `<div>`?

http://jsfiddle.net/x93uL/

```
<img src="http://i.eho.st/pjw35bzm.jpg" width="140" height="140" />

<div id="img"></div>

<style>
#img{
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
    background: url(http://i.eho.st/pjw35bzm.jpg);
}
</style>
```

Comment: You can't, although you can control `background-image`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use IMG vs. CSS background-image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492809/when-to-use-img-vs-css-background-image)

Comment: You could use CSS [`clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip), but it only works on elements with `position:absolute`. http://jsfiddle.net/x93uL/1/

Comment: @showdev This is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @showdev you may want to post an answer for this. I didn't know about this property too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS [`clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip) to crop an image, but it only works on elements with `position:absolute`.

```html
<img src="http://i.eho.st/pjw35bzm.jpg" class="two" />
```

```css
img.two {
    position:absolute;
    clip: rect(0px, 140px, 140px, 0px); 
}
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/x93uL/2/)

Answer (score 1):

**Just for the record**. You should use the background-size property if you want to make a div and its background to *appear* as an img.

Check [**this jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qTGcU/).

**HTML**:

```
<img id="Img" src="http://goo.gl/OJhO2s" />
<div id="ImgBg"></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#Img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

#ImgBg {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: url('http://goo.gl/OJhO2s');
    background-size: 100px 100px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

The `background-repeat` property is optional and only as a fallback measure in case your div happens to be bigger than the background's size.

In an opposite case:

- `img` elements can have the `block` display property and behave just like `div`s. Then you can float and hide them just like any regular `div`. Their display property is by default set to `inline-block`.

**But** `img` elements by default always scale their image `up to the size` they're set to, so there's no official way to make them clip their contents. Your only alternative are `div`s with a background image.

Comment: I think the OP wants the opposite: "How can I control the `<img>` to behave more like the `<div>`".

Comment: @arielnmz showdev is correct, I'm working with a sprite sheet but a platform that was creating `<img>` elements. I need the solution for sizing the `<img>` element as a `<div>` naturally sizes the image. @showdev your solution for using `clip: rect()` and `position:absolute` is what I was looking for.

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer he is indeed. I've checked your question again and I realized that's exactly what you need. Oh well. My answer could stay here just for the record.