# Background-image CSS

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm trying to set a background image to a html page, but the image is not appearing. The image is in the same folder as the html file.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/indexstyle.css" > 
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<heading>Overground Effective</heading>

<nav class="nav">

        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html" style="color: black;">Home</a></li>
            <li><a >About me</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="aboutme/whoami.html">Who am I</a></li>
                    <li><a href="aboutme/whatido.html">What I do</a></li>
                    <li><a href="aboutme/whatilike.html">What I like</a></li>
                </ul></li>
            <li><a href="aboutme/myskills.html">My skills</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery/gallery.html" style="color: black;">Gallery</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
</div>
```

and the CSS file:

```
body{
background-image: url("/treewithroots.jpg");
background-size: cover;
min-height: 100%;
background-position: right;
}
```

When I upload the image to Dropbox for instance, it is working just fine. How can I fix this?

Comment: TRY : remove `/` from url

Comment: @Sam1604 — That won't work. It isn't in the same directory as the stylesheet.

Comment: Same thing happens, image is still not appearing. I tried changing the folder but it doesn't work too.

Comment: Open your browser's developer tools. Look at the net tab. Find where it tries to load the image. Look at the URL it is actually requesting. Is that correct? What response is it getting?

Comment: Try adding . or .. or ~

Comment: @Quentin But in question `The image is in the same folder as the html file.` as he/she mentioned

Comment: @Sam1604 — And the code shows that the stylesheet is *not* in the same directory as the HTML document.

Comment: _“The image is in the same folder as the html file”_ – but the stylesheet itself isn’t. And – very basic knowledge – relative paths to background images are resolved against the URL of the stylesheet, not the HTML document. (Quite crappy question title btw.)

Comment: @user3798144 is the `indexstyle.css` file is in FOLDER `style` only ah?

Comment: Yes it is, by the way in firebug the background-image property is not shown at all

Comment: @user3798144 — That suggests an error elsewhere. Use a [validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use IMG vs. CSS background-image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492809/when-to-use-img-vs-css-background-image)

Comment: The working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0syp7qxj/ the problem with your image path

Answer (score 0):

Replace your style with below: because your css file is in **style folder** and your image is same folder as the html file.

```
body{
  background-image: url("../treewithroots.jpg"); // change this
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-position: right;
}
```

Suppose your folder structure as below:

```
index.html
treewithroots.jpg
style/indexstyle.css
```

Comment: This worked thank you, although I don't understand why i have to use "../" when the image is in the same folder as the html file

Comment: @user3798144 — Because URLs are resolved from the stylesheet, not the HTML document.

Comment: because your image is not in same folder where your css is.

Comment: You need to give relative path of your image

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to give proper path for this image.
try like this

```css
body{
background-image: url("http://xsights.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/branding-logo.jpg?w=624");
background-size: cover;
min-height: 100%;
background-position: right;
}
```

```html
<heading>Overground Effective</heading>

<nav class="nav">

        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html" style="color: black;">Home</a></li>
            <li><a >About me</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="aboutme/whoami.html">Who am I</a></li>
                    <li><a href="aboutme/whatido.html">What I do</a></li>
                    <li><a href="aboutme/whatilike.html">What I like</a></li>
                </ul></li>
            <li><a href="aboutme/myskills.html">My skills</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery/gallery.html" style="color: black;">Gallery</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
background-image: url("../treewithroots.jpg");
```

use as above

Answer (score -2):

You'd better use the full image url. That way you won't have to be carefull about directory structure when you place your css.

```
background-image: url("http://www.yoursite.com/treewithroots.jpg");
```