# Making a full screen image background

Tags: html, css

I basically want to make a full viewport background image.

**This is my code:**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <img src="loginBg.png" height="100%" width="100%">  
    </div>
</html>
```

**And stylesheet goes like:**

```
.container{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    left:0px;
}
```

The problem with this approach is, the image is full screen but there is some space below it, because of this space the page is scrollable. I checked it in firefox ubuntu, the white space is not there.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a background image on the body tag, which makes a lot of sense.

The problem that you noticed is due to the image being an inline element, which adds
some space below the image and triggers an overflow condition.

You can fix by adding:

```
.container img {
    display: block;
}
```

You could also use `vertical-align: top` to remove the extra white space or apply `overflow: hidden`
to hide the overflow, all workable options.

Answer (score 2):

## Real solution - CSS background images

Use a CSS background image on the body in conjunction with `no-repeat` and `background-size`.

### 2 Examples

#### With `background-size: cover` to maintain height and width ratio

```css
body {
    background: url(http://www.placehold.it/200) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

#### With `background-size: 100% 100%` to stretch

**Note:** `html,body { height: 100% }` allows the percentage background size.

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #F00 url(http://www.placehold.it/200) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Read more:

- The [background property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background)
- The [background-size property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)
- Relevant question - [When to use IMG vs. CSS background-image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492809/when-to-use-img-vs-css-background-image)

Comment: but if i select a image whose base dimensions are bigger than the diemnsions of a screen , the image is cut .. any way to display full image ?

Comment: Use `background-size: contain` as an alternative.

Comment: @TejaReddy - `background-size: 100% 100%;` would give you the same result as the `<img height="100%" width="100%" />`

Answer (score 1):

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/wopmgboL/)

use `display:block` for the image issue will be fixed

```
.container{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    left:0px;
}
img{
    display:block;
}
```