# Responsive images with javascript document.write

Tags: javascript, image, responsive-design

I want to use a responsive image on my site, load a different resolution based on screen size, and have come up with a simple javascript approach, see below.

Would there be any reason why NOT to use this solution?

Thanks!

```
<script language="Javascript"> 
var w=window.innerWidth;

if (w<=480){
    document.write('<img src="files/design/logo_480.jpg" ');        
}else if(w<=768){
    document.write('<img src="files/design/logo_768.jpg" ');   
}else{
    document.write('<img src="files/design/logo_960.jpg" >');
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the picture element that is browser built-in.
See here: http://googlechrome.github.io/samples/picture-element/

More info here [on htmlrocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/responsive/picture-element/)

Comment: great! but currently only supported in chrome. http://caniuse.com/#search=picture

Answer (score 1):

Go with the standard and use `picture` or `srcset` with `sizes` (depends on your use case).

About browser support, there are two polyfills, which you can simply use:

- [respimage](https://github.com/aFarkas/respimage)
- [picturefill](https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill)

There is really no excuse to use a partial custom solution.

Here is an [article series](http://blog.cloudfour.com/responsive-images-101-definitions/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know you browser support specification but there is HTML5 approach: [`<picture>`](http://html5hub.com/html5-picture-element/) element. But there are few browsers that it support - http://caniuse.com/#feat=picture

UPDATE

Another approach - use CSS and `@media` rules. But here you will deal with background images instead of `<img>` elements that may not fit with semantics ([When to use IMG vs. CSS background-image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492809/when-to-use-img-vs-css-background-image)):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    div.my-image {
        background-image: url(files/design/logo_480.jpg);
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    div.my-image {
        background-image: url(files/design/logo_768.jpg);
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    div.my-image {
        background-image: url(files/design/logo_960.jpg);
    }
}
```

Browser support - IE9+, Chrome 21+, FF 3.5+ (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

UPDATE #2

Another approach - instead of `write` content you can simply change `src` of existing `<img>`.

```
var w=window.innerWidth;
var img = document.getElementById("logo");

if (w<=480){
    img.src = "files/design/logo_480.jpg"
}else if(w<=768){
    img.src = "files/design/logo_768.jpg"
}else{
    img.src = "files/design/logo_960.jpg"
}
```

Comment: From what I understand, the <picture> tag is only partially supported, which means I need to create multi-browser solutions...

Comment: UPDATE #2 - works as multibrowser solution and plus it can be placed in a "resize browser" event handler to make the logo responsive

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look here why you should not use `document.write` https://stackoverflow.com/a/802943/2767886

---

You should NOT use this JS because:

- you have to add a resize-event (if the window width changes you need to update the logo size)
- on resize the new logo-url -> will be a new request to load
- it's `document.write` ...
- people that have javascript off won't see a logo

A pure CSS solution would be easier:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .logo {
        background-image: url(files/design/logo_480.jpg);
        width: 480px; height: 75px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .logo {
        background-image: url(files/design/logo_768.jpg);
        width: 768px; height: 100px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .logo {
        background-image: url(files/design/logo_960.jpg);
        width: 960px; height: 150px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your link to the why-not-use-DW article. I need to think a bit about the need for a resize-event. With this script I can serve an image for smaller resolution devices, and how likely is a resize on a large desktop screen?