# Replace img to background-image div with php

Tags: php, html, css

Is there a way to replace img tag with div tag like below?

Original html:

```
<div class="article">
  <img src="/images/img-1.jpg" alt="alt for image">
</div>
```

Replaced html:

```
<div class="article">
 <div style="background: transparent url(/images/img-1.jpg) no-repeat;
 background-position: center center; background-size: cover; width: 566px; 
 height: 576px;">alt for image</div>
</div>
```

(Optional) Also is it possible to use the width and height from the parent div i.e. article class in my example instead of defining fixed `width: 566px; height: 576px;`?

If it's possible, I want to use the `str_replace` function.

```
str_replace('?????', '?????', $article);
```

**Edit:**

There may be multiple elements with class article  and there may be other elements inside article class div and from which I need to change img to div.

**Edit2:**

I was meaning as if I may have any content inside article div and just want to replace the img with div.

I may have:

```
<div class="article">
  <h1>heading</h1>
  <p>paragraph</p>
  <img src="/images/img-1.jpg" alt="alt for image">
</div>
```

Or I may have:

```
<div class="article">
  <h3>heading</h3>
  <p><img src="/images/img-1.jpg" alt="alt for image"> some paragraph </p>
</div>
```

So, I may have anything inside `.article` div and from which I wanted to replace img to div like

**From:**

```
<img src="/images/img-1.jpg" alt="alt for image" here-may-be-another-attribute-too>
```

**To:**

```
<div style="background: transparent url(/images/img-1.jpg) no-repeat;">alt for image</div>
```

Comment: Just use `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` to fit parent size.

Comment: I need to define in pixel.

Comment: If HTML is dynamically created, you will need preg_replace function. second question - yes.

Comment: @nevermind can you please provide me an answer using preg_replace?

Comment: jquery would be better if it's not compulsory to do with php.

Comment: I need to do it with php.

Comment: Are you alright to use something like `simplehtmldom`?

Comment: @henry already answered with that. And I don't..

Comment: How is the html generated? Are these static pages or is it created with php?

Comment: Side note: There are inherent differences between using the HTML-native `img` tag and using CSS to apply a background-image. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29313643/2502532) may be worth considering as you develop your solution.

Comment: @JonC This is dynamically created with php.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [PHP’s native DOM library](http://php.net/book.dom) to found and replace html. I wrote some example, you adapt for your case. Hope help.

**Updated code:**

```
$html_str = '<div class="article newclass" id="some_id">
  <h1>heading</h1>
  <p>paragraph</p>
  <img src="images/image.png" alt="alt for image">
  <br>
  <h3>
  <p>paragraph</p>
    <img src="images/image2.png" alt="alt for image3">
  </h3>
  </div>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html_str);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->query('//div[contains(@class, "article")]//img') as $img) {

  $new_img = replace($img, $width = '566', $height = '576');

  $replacement = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
  $replacement->appendXML($new_img);

  $img->parentNode->replaceChild($replacement, $img);

}

$new_html = $dom->saveXml();
echo $new_html;

function replace($img, $width, $height) {

  $href = $img->getAttribute('src');
  $alt = $img->getAttribute('alt');

  $new_img = '<div style="background: transparent url('.$href.') no-repeat;
    background-position: center center; background-size: cover; width: '.$width.'px;
    height: '.$height.'px;">'.$alt.'</div>';

  return $new_img;
}
```

replace function stay the same only change part where manage with DOM

Comment: In that case I change little the code for more classes in div and more image inside the article class

Comment: Yes, I understand but need little time to update the code :)

Comment: Thanks. I hope you'll provide your answer as soon as possible. I'm currently providing my ending bounty for you.

Comment: This is working fine when used in index.php but when I try somewhere else from where the html is generated it's showing me Fatal Error: Call to undefined function replace(). Any thought?

Comment: System not found the replace() function, need include file where you defined those function.

Answer (score 8):

use the php-class simplehtmldom (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)
you can find and modify the HTML-Dom with CSS-like selectors.

```
<?php
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

// Create DOM from string
$html = str_get_html('<div class="article">
  <img src="/images/img-1.jpg" alt="alt for image">
</div>');

$html->find('div.article', 0)->innertext = '<div style="background: transparent url(/images/img-1.jpg) no-repeat;
 background-position: center center; background-size: cover; width: 566px; 
 height: 576px;">alt for image</div>';

/** 
 * Output: <div id="article"><div style="background: transparent url(/images/img-1.jpg) no-repeat;
 * background-position: center center; background-size: cover; width: 566px; 
 * height: 576px;">alt for image</div></div>
 */
echo $html; 
?>
```

Comment: No answer is provided with what I actually wanted. So, I must use your answer. But I couldn't find simple_html_dom.php, can you link it?

Answer (score 8):

Here you go. A tested and working solution. The error reporting is there in case PHP throws any errors. The child div also inherits the width and height of the parent div.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

ini_set("log_errors", 1);

/**
 * Display of all other errors
 */
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

/**
 * Display of all startup errors
 */
ini_set("display_startup_errors", 1);

$content = '
<div class="article">
  <h1>heading</h1>
  <p>paragraph</p>
  <img src="/images/img-1.jpg" alt="alt for image">
</div>
';

$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadHTML($content);
$domElemsToRemove = [];

$domXpath = new DOMXpath($domDocument);
$nodes = $domXpath->query('//div[@class="article"]/img');


$newNode ="<div style='background: transparent url(/images/img-1.jpg) no-repeat; width: inherit; height: inherit; background-position: center center; background-size: cover; width: 566px; height: 576px;'>alt for new image</div>";
$newDom = $domDocument->createDocumentFragment();
$newDom->appendXML($newNode);


foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->appendChild($newDom);
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}

echo $domDocument->saveHTML();
?>
```

Comment: This replace all. Suppose if I have other elements like p, h1, etc... inside article that should not be replaced. As I am talking about to replace img tags from article class from whole html.

Comment: Please check updated question so that you may understand.

Comment: I understand your question, but I'm busy at the moment. Will edit my answer later.

Answer (score 4):

1. To do that you need to work with the [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function
2. Try to set height and width as "inherit"

For your Problem try this:

```
$string = ' <div class="article">
                <img src="/images/img-1.jpg" alt="alt for image">
            </div>';
preg_match('@<div class="article">(.*?)</div>@is', $string, $replace);
preg_match('/<img src="(.*?)" alt="(.*?)">/', $string, $matches);

$string = str_replace($replace[1], '<div style="background: transparent url('.$matches[1].') no-repeat; background-position: center center; background-size: cover; width: inherit; height: inherit;">'.$matches[2].'</div>', $string);
```

Comment: Where is the answer to OP's question?

Comment: The question was: Is there a way to replace img tag with div tag like below?

Answer (score 4):

To go from the old html to the new html we need to know two things:

1. the `src` attribute
2. the `alt` attribute

Once we know these two values we can easily create the new html format. I do that as follows:

```
<?php
$orig_html = <<<HERE
<div class="article">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="alt for image">
</div>
HERE;

echo new_html($orig_html);

/* helper function to get the value of an attribute:
$attribute: the attribute you want to check (e.g. src)
$source: The html you want it to parse */
function get_attribute($attribute, $source) {
    $query  = '/' . $attribute . '="([^"]*)"/i';
    $result = array();
    preg_match($query, $source, $result);
    return $result[1];
}

/* helper function to return new html from the old html
$source: the old html */
function new_html($source) {
    $src = get_attribute('src', $source);
    $alt = get_attribute('alt', $source);

    return <<<HERE
 <div class="article">
   <div style="background: transparent url($src) no-repeat;
   background-position: center center; background-size: cover;">$alt</div>
  </div>
HERE;
}
?>
```

We can't use php to read the width and height of the parent (the article class), unless the width and height is defined in the markup. From your example it doesn't seem like these values are in the markup, so I'm assuming these dimensions are provided by css?

Instead you can always style the image with the following css:
`.article > div {width: 100%; height: 100%;}`.

Comment: I want to replace from all html documents.

Comment: Suppose $article is full html and then printing $article should now be replaced version of img to div and others same.

Comment: @NavinRauniyar I don't follow your comments. Would `$article` be a full html page? As in something [like this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_basic_document)?

Comment: In that case I'd suggest using @mlivan's approach, did you manage to get it working in the end?

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like this:

```
$content = "this is something with an <img src=\"test.png\"/> in it.";
$replaceWith = '<div style="background:url($1)"></div>';
$content = preg_replace('/<img\s+src="([^"]+)"[^>]+>/i', $replaceWith, $content); 
echo $content;
```

Change `$replaceWith` according to your markup.

Comment: great. But I'm talking about to replace only those images from .article div. any suggestion?

Comment: if you are trying to change img's in .article div then you should play with PHP native library called DomDocument.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to replace img tag with div tag like below?

**YES**

a). **DOM** (prefered way)

b). **REGEX**

both methods are already implemented in other answers, use one you like

**Note:** if the html is generated dynamically by php, i would advise you to extract `alt` and `src` attributes value with `preg_match_all` [regex here](https://regex101.com/r/wC8xQ9/1) and then create a string from that, that would give you more flexibility, for e.g:

```
$str ='<div class="article"><img src="/images/img-1.jpg" alt="alt for image"></div>';

preg_match_all('`src=(?:[\'"])(.*)[\'"].*alt=(?:[\'"])(.*)[\'"].*`U', $str, $matches);

$desiredHTML = <<<HTML
<div class="article">
 <div style="background: transparent url({$matches[1][0]}) no-repeat;
 background-position: center center; background-size: cover; width: 566px; 
 height: 576px;">{$matches[2][0]}</div>
</div>
HTML;
```

> is it possible to use the width and height from the parent div?

**YES**
by using following js code you can do that, since you can't find out the height of `article` div without rendering, and you want them in pixels, you have to use javascript

```
var cl = document.getElementsByClassName('article');
    for (var i = 0; i <= cl.length; i++)
    {
        var width = cl[i].style.width;
        var height = cl[i].style.height;
        cl[i].firstElementChild.style.width = width;
        cl[i].firstElementChild.style.height = height;
    };
```

> If it's possible, I want to use the str_replace function?

**NO**, it's not possible with **str_replace** function.

Answer (score 4):

YES.

But str_replace can not do this alone.

```
$article =<<<'EOT'
  <div class="article">
    <img src="/images/img-1.jpg" alt="alt for image">
  </div>
EOT;

// img -> div
$res = str_replace('<img', '<div', $article);
// src -> style
$res = preg_replace('/src="([^"]+)"/i', 'style="background: transparent url($1) no-repeat; background-position: center center; background-size: cover; width: 566px; height: 576px;"', $res);
// alt -> innerHTML
$res = preg_replace('/ alt="(.*)">/i', '>$1</div>', $res);
echo $res;
```

Answer (score 4):

using [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php) :

```
//your html code in a variable
$source = '<div class="article">
  <img src="/images/img-1.jpg" alt="alt for image1">
</div>
<div class="article">
  <img src="/images/img-5.jpg" alt="alt for image5">
</div>';

//class
class PregReplace{
    private static $instance;
    private $source;
    public $css = array('width'=>'600','height'=>'800','background-size'=>'cover','background-position'=>'center center','background'=>'transparent url($1) no-repeat');
    private $replace;
    private $result;
    private $pattern = '/\<div\s?class="article">\n?\r?\n?.*img\s?src="(.*?)"\salt="(.*?)".*\n?\r?\n?\<\/div\>/m';
    public function __construct(){

    }

    public function loadreplace(){
        $this->replace='<div class="article">
     <div style="background:'.$this->css['background'].'; background-position:'.$this->css['background-position'].'; background-size:'.$this->css['background-size'].'; width:'.$this->css['width'].'px; 
     height: '.$this->css['height'].'px;">$2</div>
    </div>';
    }

    public function setcss($array){
        $this->css = $array;
    }
    public function setsource($value){
        $this->source = $value;
        return $this;
    }
    public function setreplace($value){
        $this->replace = $value;
    }
    public function replacing(){
        $this->loadreplace();
        $this->result = preg_replace($this->pattern,$this->replace,$this->source);
        return $this;
    }
    public function result(){
        return $this->result;
    }
}

//process with preg_replace
$result = new PregReplace();
//you can set your css
$result->css['width'] = '566';
$result->css['height'] = '576';
//
var_dump($result->setsource($source)->replacing()->result());
```

Comment: This replaces only if <div class="article"><img .. /></div> is matched but I want to replace <img /> only from whole html which is inside <div class="article" /> meaning inside this there may be any other elements such as p, h3, etc. but just wanted to replace img...

Answer (score 4):

Here is my approach, call normal Java Script from php:

```
<div class="article">
    <img src="../images/img-1.jpg" alt="alt for image">
</div>

<?php
$removeOldContent = '<script>document.getElementsByClassName("article")[0].remove();</script>';
$newContent = '<div class="article"><div style="background: transparent url(../images/img-1.jpg) no-repeat;
 background-position: center center; background-size: cover; width: 566px;
 height: 576px;">alt for image</div></div>';

$content = $removeOldContent . $newContent;

// this could be you replacing condition
// false will keep old content
// true will remove old content and view new content
if (false)
    echo $content;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could read the file into a string, replace to your needs, then write back to either a new file or overwrite the original. Anyway, I'd probably just add a class for the div. Inline css is a pain.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`replaceWith` method](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/):

> The `.replaceWith()` method, like most jQuery methods, returns the
>   jQuery object so that other methods can be chained onto it. However,
>   it must be noted that the original jQuery object is returned. This
>   object refers to the element that has been removed from the DOM, not
>   the new element that has replaced it.
>
> The `.replaceWith()` method removes all data and event handlers
>   associated with the removed nodes.

```
$('.article img').replaceWith(function(i, v){
    return $('<div/>', {
        style: 'background-image: url('+this.src+')',
        html: '<div style="background: transparent url(/images/img-1.jpg)no-repeat;background-position: center center; background-size: cover; width: 566px; height: 576px;">alt for image</div>'
    })
})
```

OR

```
echo "$('.article img').replaceWith(function(i, v){
            return $('<div/>', {
                style: 'background-image: url('+this.src+')',
                html: '<div style=\"background: transparent url(/images/img-1.jpg)no-repeat;background-position: center center; background-size: cover; width: 566px; height: 576px;\">alt for image</div>'
            })
        })";
```

### [Here is my jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/FD9gV/)

Comment: I'm talking about php not jquery.

Comment: You can convert this script code into php. Means put this script code into echo "..." .

Comment: Thanks giving for appreciation :)

Comment: More explanation i have edited. You can check it. I hope you can understated properly.

Comment: When you copy something verbatim, even if it's documentation, **you must link to the documentation and quote-format the copied text**, otherwise it looks like plagiarism.

Comment: This is not a server side php solution

Answer (score 3):

This method is almost entirely `preg_replace`; it does have a few nice additions:

1. The CSS values `w x h` are added as part of the replacement.
2. All of the other main values (`class`, `href`, and `alt`) are dynamically replaced.

It basically uses two patterns, the first parses the `CSS` and the second replaces the `<div>`.

**Code**:

```
<?php

$str = '<div class="article"><img src="/images/image.png" alt="alt for image"></div>';
$css = '<style> .article { font-size:16px; font-weight:bold; width:566px; height:576px; } </style>
';

function replace($str, $css) {

    preg_match( '@>\s\.(.+)\s{\s(.*)\s}@', $css, $res);

        $style['class'] = $res[1];
        $attrs = explode("; ", $res[2]);

        foreach ($attrs as $attr) {
                if (strlen(trim($attr)) > 0) {
                $kv = explode(":", trim($attr));
                $style[trim($kv[0])] = trim($kv[1]);
            }
        }

$rep = '<div class="$1">
 <div style="background: transparent url($2) no-repeat; 
 background-position: center center; background-size: cover; width: '.$style['width'].';
 height: '.$style['height'].'">$3</div>
</div>
';

    return preg_replace( '@.+class="(.+)"><.*="(.+)"\\salt="(.+)".+@', $rep, $str );
}
    $str = replace($str, $css);
?>

<html>
<head>
<?php echo $css; ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $str; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**Example**:

**http://ideone.com/TJHR1b**

Answer (score 2):

This will accomplish what you are trying to do. Hope this helps.

```
$prev_str = '<div class="article"><img src="pics/flower.jpg" alt="alt for image"></div>';
preg_match('/'.preg_quote("<div class=\"").'(.*?)'.preg_quote("\"><img").'/is', $prev_str, $class);
$class_name=$class[1];//article
preg_match('/'.preg_quote("<img src=\"").'(.*?)'.preg_quote("\" alt=\"").'/is', $prev_str, $image);
$image_path=$image[1];//pics/flower.jpg
preg_match('/'.preg_quote("alt=\"").'(.*?)'.preg_quote("\"><").'/is', $prev_str, $alt);
$alt=$alt[1];//alt for image
//size that we are going to use in the div as well image div
$width="200px";
$height="200px";
echo '
<style>
div.article{
    min-height:'.$height.';
    width:'.$width.';
}
</style>';
/** additional hints in css formatting
div.article div{
    //display: inline-block;
    //width:inherit;
    //height:inherit;
    //width:100%;
    //height:100%;
}
**/
echo '<div class="'.$class_name.'">';
echo '<div style="background: transparent url('.$image_path.') no-repeat;
 background-position: center center; background-size: cover;width:'.$height.'; 
 height: '.$width.';">'.$alt.'</div>
</div>';
```

Comment: it may not be the best answer but why down voted? its better to comment the reason if it needs to be down voted. :) cool.. This answer was tested, its simple and accomplish the questioners need clearly :)