# Rounded corners in safari/chrome are not rounded on hover for first second

Tags: html, css, rounded-corners

I have a problem with Safari/Chrome.
On these browsers ( on hover ) my rounded corners make a square and then go back to be rounded.[Here is the code](http://jsfiddle.net/Lqfmdah5/6/)

```
CSS
    div.img-cont {
            float:left; 
            position:relative; 
            margin:10px 20px 0 0px;
            width:180px; 
            height:160px;    
            border:0px solid #FFF;
            overflow:hidden !important;
             -webkit-border-radius:5px; 
                -moz-border-radius:5px; 
                 -ms-border-radius:5px;
                  -o-border-radius:5px; 
                     border-radius:5px;            
    } 
    div.img-zoom { 
            float:left; 
            position:relative; 
            margin:-20px 0 0 -20px; 
            width:220px; 
            height:200px;
            background-position:center center !important;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
               -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
                -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
                 -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
                    transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    } 
    .transition {
            -webkit-transform: scale(0.93,0.93); 
               -moz-transform: scale(0.93,0.93);
                -ms-transform: scale(0.93,0.93);
                 -o-transform: scale(0.93,0.93);
                    transform: scale(0.93,0.93);    
    } 
    .f_border{
             -webkit-border-radius:5px; 
                -moz-border-radius:5px; 
                 -ms-border-radius:5px;
                  -o-border-radius:5px; 
                     border-radius:5px;  
    }
```

HTML

```
       <div class="Box_1x1_front" style="height:180px; background:#eaeaea; ">
            <a class="leftAllPlace" rel="thumb" title="" href="http://bonavestis.pl/image/cache/data/Produkty/Sukienki/Sukienka%20JUST%20UNIQUE%20Bandażowa%20W%20Beżu%20+Złoto/Image001-885x885.jpg">
                <div class="img-cont f_border">
                    <div class="img-zoom img_2">
                        <div style="float:left; width:100%; height:100%; background-image:url('http://bonavestis.pl/image/cache/data/Produkty/Sukienki/Sukienka%20JUST%20UNIQUE%20Bandażowa%20W%20Beżu%20+Złoto/Image001-372x372.jpg');"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT HERE

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.img_2').hover(function() {
            $(this).addClass('transition');
        }, function() {
            $(this).removeClass('transition');
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Its like zoom out div with background-image inside div with rounded corners
Any ideas how to fix this...

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/Lqfmdah5/6/
```

Comment: Here is the same example with less code, but there is still a problem with corners in chrome/safari https://jsfiddle.net/wLrkk6bm/

Answer (score 2):

1)

As @Squideyes mentioned there is an only-CSS approach how to add a transition.

Just add CSS selector:

```
.img_2:hover {

}
```

instead of `.transition`

2)

Also I recommend using `<img>` instead of `background-images` of `<div>` in your case because from my point of view image here is a content-part element and assumes using `<img>`.

More info: [IMG vs background-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492809/when-to-use-img-vs-css-background-image)

3)

And about the `scale` problem in Chrome. Seems that there is a glitch with `transition` and `border-radious` in Webkit. Try to change `width` and `height` instead as a workaround.

Check out https://jsfiddle.net/Lqfmdah5/7/

Answer (score 1):

The transition that is being applied in JavaScript takes away the CSS `border-radius`. The following [method](http://jsfiddle.net/55jpa56h/2/) is a lot cleaner and means you don't need to use JavaScript:

**HTML**

```
<div class="rounded-box">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.rounded-box {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: url(http://bit.ly/1MjBCE6) no-repeat center;
    background-size: 100px 100px;
    transition: background-size 0.2s ease-in;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.rounded-box:hover {
   background-size: 200px 200px;
}
```

Comment: Seems Tadeusz Majkowski wants the image to be zoomed inside some wrapper with border radius. But in your example an image has border radius.

Comment: Good call. I've updated my answer and the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/55jpa56h/2.

Comment: Here is the same with less code but there is still problem with corners in chrome/safari https://jsfiddle.net/wLrkk6bm/

Comment: My updated version zooms the background image only and maintains the border-radius: http://jsfiddle.net/55jpa56h/2.

Comment: Great just like i want it :)

Comment: Awesome :) You'll just need to adjust the background-position. You may also want to consider disabling this for touch devices by using modernizr touch: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/detect-touch-device-modernizr.