# What is going on with this <img> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, image

When I come across websites that I really like, I often take a look at their page source just to see if I can learn any new web tricks. I came across [TopTal's site](http://www.toptal.com), and when looking at how they import their main logo's `<img/>` tag (top + left of homepage), I was astonished to see:

```
<div class="page_header_top-logotype"> = $0
    <a class="logo is-big is-link for- " href="http://www.toptal.com"></a>
</div>
```

**Ba-ba-bwhat?!?!**

- Where is the actual logo (an image or `<img/>` tag) pulled in?!?!
- What in the world is that `= $0`?!?!

Am I missing something obvious, or is this some clever trick to pull an image in from some custom webfont/thing?

Comment: It's called CSS, you can actually add background images to elements in it !

Comment: Thanks @adeneo (+1) - does this trick have a name inside CSS-land? if you could explain it and give a link to a tutorial that covers this trick, I'll happily give you the green check!

Comment: Why the downvote? This shows effort/research, is on topic, isn't a dupe and is an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Unhand me you fiend!

Comment: Pretty basic CSS http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Comment: You look at the source, find the included CSS, problem solved...

Comment: Thanks so much @Nikki9696 - however your link doesn't explain what the `= $0` is. Perhaps any thoughts?

Comment: More interesting, what does <div class="page_header_top-logotype"> = $0 mean. The other part is just using a background in css  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492809/when-to-use-img-vs-css-background-image?rq=1)

Comment: I checked the source and do not see a $0 in chrome. What browser are you using? Unless script or CSS is doing fun things with siblings or next child, it's just plain text.

Comment: @smeeb "= $0" is just plain text (content). Doesn't mean anything in general. Might mean something specific for that particular web page's content. Odds are it's just badly entered dummy text to make some CMS field happy.

Comment: The = $0 might have just  been text from an estimate, like a dollar amount that is displayed as plain text.

Comment: I didn't see it either, not sure where did the OP find it.

Comment: I've checked the source, and the console, and can't find `= $0` anywhere either ?

Comment: And to be clear, that's not in any way part of the HTML. It's just text that happens to be surrounded by HTML.

Comment: The mistery of the zero dollars in toptal.

Comment: So when/why would someone use these 'CSS Backgrounds'? Are they more efficient for the browser?

Comment: In any case, it's just content in a div based off the OP, and has no meaning.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492809/when-to-use-img-vs-css-background-image?rq=1 here a difference between techniques

Comment: Because it's easier to change css classes than html source, especially for larger sites with content management systems, frameworks, CSS pre-processors, and other stuff. Especially once media types and responsive design happens.

Comment: This isn't a trick, this is just very basic CSS. Normally you don't want to use an `<img>` tag for images that are not intended to be main contents. Almost every site does this, including StackOverflow.

Comment: How is this possibly a dupe?!?! When I asked the question, I didnt even know what CSS backgrounds were!!!! Lemmings!!! All of you, lemmmmminngggsss

Answer (score 3):

It's not a trick, it's just basic styling with CSS

```
<a class="logo is-big is-link for- " href="http://www.toptal.com"></a>

<style type="css/text"> // or in a .css file
    .logo.is-big {background-image : url("someimage.jpg")}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks @adeneo (+1) - any idea about that `= $0`?

Comment: The `= $0` does not show for me, nor is it doing anything.

Comment: The `= $0` is something that appears in the DOM debugger in some browsers. I'm not sure what it signifies, but it's not actually part of the page.

Answer (score 3):

Like the commenters said, the logo is set via CSS, specifically... this rule.

```
.logo.is-link {
    transition-duration: 200ms;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-property: transform, opacity;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
.logo.is-big {
    width: 105px;
    height: 35px;
    background-image: url("//assets.toptal.io/assets/public/blocks/logo/big-21c32f3cb60e0b8cf3c514a8fc5fd905.png");
    background-size: 105px 35px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

The first class applies `display: inline-block;` which lets you set the dimensions and the second class sets up the actual background image that TopTal uses.

Please see [this StackOverflow discussion for more information about when to use img vs when to use css background-image.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492809/when-to-use-img-vs-css-background-image)

Comment: i think you need to make the anchor tag display:block

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f0ykqtu6/1/

Comment: Thanks @Toni W (+1) - any idea about that `= $0`? Also, when would someone use these 'CSS Backgrounds' and why? Are they somehow more efficient for the browser?

Comment: I actually dont see that in the source anywhere. How did you view the source?