# Use an image instead of a Bootstrap's glyphicon

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I would like to use a custom image in an `input-group` instead of a Bootstrap glyphicon **without padding bottom** (my image touch the bottom of the button), as you can see on this picture:[image]

---

Actually, I use Bootstrap's `glyphicon glyphicon-search`:

```
<div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Rechercher un produit, une référence ..."/>
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        <span class="hidden-xs text-upper-style">
          Rechercher</span>
      </span>
</div>
```

[image]

My issue is that I fail to replace glyphicon by my picture in my search bar.

I've tried to create CSS to mimic those of Bootstrap, but it always render bad:

---

**CSS**

```
.glyphi {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
.glyphi.search {
    background: url(../img/header/search.png);
    background-size: cover; 
}
.glyphi.normal { 
    width: 28px; //But Bootstrap glyphicon is 16x16...
    height: 16px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
```

---

Note that my image is not square (60x37 px).

Here is the picture that should replace the `glyphicon`:

[image]

What is the best Bootstrap way to do that?
[Here is a Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/tVROdOPG6i) of my code.

Thanks! :)

Comment: you do not want any changes on HTML?

Comment: You can change HTML as you want, it just should renders like my picture, and be responsive (renders well on a small screen) :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use simple `img` inside `.input-group-addon` instead of `span.glyphicon` and with some negative margins you can get the result you want.

**HTML**

```
<div class="input-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Rechercher un produit, une référence ...">      
   <span class="input-group-addon">
       <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vr0uy.png">
       <span class="hidden-xs text-upper-style">Rechercher</span>
   </span>      
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.rechercheProduit .input-group-addon img{
  height: 24px;
  margin-right: -16px;
  margin-bottom: -6px;
  vertical-align:text-bottom; /* align the text */
}
```

---

[**Updated Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/x3pakSuR1e)

Comment: For the time being, it is the best answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You should have a look on how the glyphicon `span` works:
If you inspect it, you will see that the interesting part in this `span` is actually its **pseudo-element**, the `:before` that calls a font of icons as a content.

[image: Screenshot of the Glyphicon span behaviour in the DOM]

---

A few solutions are actually possible to resolve your problem.

### Override

1. One of the solution would be to override that pseudo element by
   redeclaring its content:

   ```
   .rechercheProduit .input-group-addon {
     /* Declaring the parent as relative so the .glyphicon-search child span 
        as a position absolute to its parent.. 
        That probably doesn't make any sense. */
     position: relative;
   }
   .rechercheProduit .glyphicon-search {
     /* 'absolute' in the .input-group-addon context */
     position: absolute; 
     top: auto;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 5px;
     height: 80%;
     width: auto; 
     overflow: hidden;
   }
     .rechercheProduit .glyphicon-search:before {
       content: '';
       display: block;
       width: 50px; /* Generic width */
       height: 100%;
       background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/vr0uy.png') no-repeat;
       background-size: auto 100%;
     }
   .rechercheProduit .text-upper-style {
     /* relative to its context. Especially here to deal with the display order. */
     position: relative;
     margin-left: 20px;
   }
   ```

   [Demo 1](http://codepen.io/AlexisBertin/pen/8e22a4d08d7450617bded5191594d14d)

---

### Custom span

2. Another solution, which would probably be better, would be to
   actually create your own span with your own pseudo-element (CSS is
   similar to the last example, renaming the `.glyphicon-search` part
   obviously):

   ```
   <span class="input-group-addon">
     <span class="search-icon"></span>
     <span class="hidden-xs text-upper-style">
     Rechercher</span>
   </span>
   ```

   [Demo 2](http://codepen.io/AlexisBertin/pen/d9f0970a138b3afea49d521b2af08013)

---

### Image

3. Even if I personally prefer having the icon as a background image
   here (have a look on [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492809/when-to-use-img-vs-css-background-image)), declaring
   the icon as an image is another solution that works.

   c.f. the answer of *tmg* about that.

---

### About the rest

To go beyond with your code, you should think about the fact that you are working in a form with an `input[type="text"]` as main input.

You’ll have to submit this form and unless you deal with a *click event* on this main span to submit your form, you’ll have to declare your *rechercher* span as an `input` as well (`type=“submit”`).

That would be semantically more correct and easier for you to deal with this button action in the future.

My final proposition would then be:
(also considering the "custom" span icon solution)

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Rechercher un produit, une référence ...">
  <label class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="search-icon"></span>
    <input type="submit" value="Rechercher" class="hidden-xs text-upper-style" />
  </label>
</div>
```

-

```
.text-upper-style {
  background: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
}
.rechercheProduit .input-group-addon {
  border: 0;
}
```

[Demo 3](http://codepen.io/AlexisBertin/pen/d8aa0b63cd0c2234277c3a930c226cab)

**About the responsive**, just declare a `min-width` on your label:

```
.rechercheProduit .input-group-addon {
  min-width: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

---

Hope this makes sense. I'm open to any kind of suggestion, edit, etc...

[Bon chance!](https://youtu.be/cOsqUta2ol4?t=43)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your (complete) answer! I enjoyed reading the different ideas that you mention. I liked the second way your purpose, but on a [small screen it rendered bad](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/700328Capture.png) :-(. Dont worry it does not need to be posted, this searchbar just update an [AngularJS ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)!
 PS : URL of your solution #1 gaves 404.

Comment: The 3 demos are now updated so the first link works and the 2 lines about the responsive (`min-width` and `overflow: hidden`) are now declared everywhere. Glad it helped though.

Comment: Mistalis, did you manage to fix your issue? Which way did you chose at the end?

Comment: You have presented a wide range of solutions, so I gave you the bounty for that.
Your #2 solution really render well, but tmg's one seemed simpler (less code, more reusable) and better matches what I want in this specific case! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have to hide the default glyphicon then use custom image.
Try these lines:

```
.glyphicon-search::before {
    content:none!important;
}
.glyphicon-search {
    background-image:url(../ur-image);
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Comment: I would prefer not to override Bootstrap's classes (I may use `glyphicon-search` in a normal way)... Moreover, your answer does not bring more than [Sanjeev K's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38050120/4927984).

Answer (score 2):

It's as easy as replace span glyphicon tag for your custom image tag forcing correct height and deleting top and bottom padding from text 'rechercher'.

So, add this to your html:

```
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <img height="25" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vr0uy.png" alt="custom-magnifier">
    <span class="hidden-xs text-upper-style">
      Rechercher</span>
  </span>
```

So, add this to your css:

```
.rechercheProduit .input-group-addon {
  padding: 0 12px;
}
.rechercheProduit .input-group-addon {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Here you have an example:
http://www.bootply.com/CAPEgZTt3J

Answer (score 1):

Here is the css that will replace the search icon

```
.glyphi {
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/vr0uy.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 / contain;
 display: inline-block;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 height: 16px;
 line-height: 1;
 position: relative;
 top: 1px;
 width: 60px;
 }
```

You also need to resize the search icon because the parent element has padding.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What would you suggest to `resize the search icon because the parent element has padding`? :)

Comment: The height of the icon should be max 16 pixels as per your bootply.

Comment: Please take a look to the first screenshot of my answer: the image is more bigger. With your code it is pretty small :)

Comment: actually I had to resize it to fit in space available. you can try resizing, but make sure to expand the same height to input box as well

Comment: @Mistalis I have found another approach to doing this, instead of using glyohicon icon, I used CSS Pseudo-element, take a look at this Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/cppgw36p/2/

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use a background-image on the input-group-addon + some padding-left and remove the glyphicon entirely:

```css
* {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}
.rechercheProduit .input-group-addon {
  border: 0px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #004392;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.rechercheProduit:hover {
  color: #fbba00;
}
.rechercheProduit .form-control,
.rechercheProduit .input-group-addon {
  border: solid 2px #004392;
}
.rechercheProduit .input-group-addon {
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-w: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #004392;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/vr0uy.png");
  background-position: 6px 3px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  padding-left: 38px;
}
.rechercheProduit .input-group-addon:hover {
  color: #fbba00;
}
.text-upper-style {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-xs-8 col-md-6">
  <form class="form-horizontal rechercheProduit">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Rechercher un produit, une référence ..." type="text">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="text-upper-style">
          Rechercher</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

You need of course to change the background-position, background-size, padding-left so it fits your image.

Adjust the `background-size` to define the size of the image, change the `background-position` to position the image inside the `span` and change the `padding-left` value to move the text further to the right.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but one of my main goal is `without padding bottom (my image touch the bottom of the button), as you can see on this picture` as I said in my question :-)
It seems [your code](http://www.bootply.com/lypqqz9C3j) does not match this condition

Comment: There's acutally no padding. Like I said: You just need to adjust the background-size (for example to "contain"). I edited my answer to show you what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

This is my attemp, i hope this one can help you. i use `absolute`. Just try to view in full page, i working the responsive design.

```css
* {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
}
.rechercheProduit .input-group-addon {
  border: 0px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #004392;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.rechercheProduit:hover {
  color: #fbba00;
}
.rechercheProduit .form-control,
.rechercheProduit .input-group-addon {
  border: solid 2px #004392;
}
.rechercheProduit .input-group-addon {
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-w: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #004392;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.rechercheProduit .input-group-addon:hover {
  color: #fbba00;
}

.text-upper-style {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.glyphicon-search:before {
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vr0uy.png)center center;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 25px;
    width: 42px;
    content: '';
    z-index: 99;
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    left: -8px;
}
.glyphicon-search:before{
  content: '' !important;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
  .cus-icon{
    padding: 0 10px;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-xs-8 col-md-6">
  <form class="form-horizontal rechercheProduit">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Rechercher un produit, une référence ...">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search cus-icon"></span>
        <span class="hidden-xs text-upper-style">
          Rechercher</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting. Do you think this code can be used to change another Bootstrap's glyyhicon, or is it too specific?

Answer (score 1):

You can override `.glyphicon` and set your image as a `background` for it and remove its `icon`

```
.rechercheProduit .input-group-addon span.glyphicon{
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vr0uy.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height: 24px;
    width: 38px;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    margin: -6px -13px 0 0;
    top: auto;
    bottom: -6px;
    z-index: 0;
}

.rechercheProduit .input-group-addon span.glyphicon:before{
    content:'';  // To remove its default icon
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ms5e0535/

Comment: According to you, what is the benefit of this solution compared to [tmg's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38138885/4927984)? :-)

Comment: Tmg's solution is the best in this case of course. I just add my solution just in case you can't or don't want to change your HTML. But if it possible to make a change in your HTML structure so the other solution is the best for you.