# How do I place an image behind my navigation links?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place an image behind my navigation bar and I want it fixed on the top right side of the page but I'm having a hard time trying to do so.
Here's what I want the page to look like:

[image: I want the page to look like this]

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="navbarcn">
<div class="navbar">
    <img src="bamboo.png">
    <nav class="header">
        <a class="active" href="javascript:;">HOME</a>
        <a class="headl" href="menu.html">MENU</a>
        <a class="headl" href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
    </nav>  
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.navbarcn{
  margin:0;
  height:120px;
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
}  
.navbar{
  float:right;
  text-align:right;
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
}  
.navbar img{
  width:250px;
  float:right;
}  
.navbar a{
  padding:10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size:1.4em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: just make your image as a background of your navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should not use an `img` for this kind of styling. Use CSS. (Here I have commented out the image).

```
<div class="navbarcn">
<div class="navbar">
    <!--  <img src="bamboo.png"> -->
    <nav class="header">
        <a class="active" href="javascript:;">HOME</a>
        <a class="headl" href="menu.html">MENU</a>
        <a class="headl" href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
    </nav>  
</div>
```

Next, add some background properties to target your `navbar`.

```
.navbarcn{
    margin:0;
    height:120px;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
}

.navbar{
    float:right;
    text-align:right;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;

    background-image: url(https://placekitten.com/100/50);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top right;
}  

/*.navbar img{
    width:250px;
    float:right;}
*/

.navbar a{
    padding:10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:1.4em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lf4exsv7/

Using IMG vs CSS background-image: [When to use IMG vs. CSS background-image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492809/when-to-use-img-vs-css-background-image)

Answer (score 0):

#### Give .navbarcn background image

```
.navbarcn{
margin:0;
height:120px;
position:fixed;
width:100%;
background-image:url('bamboo.png');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.navnarcn`'s parent must explicitely have the css property `position` defined.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, an
answer really needs a bit more detail than this.  Please
[edit] to provide example code to show what you mean.
Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

using background would be a better solution but this is also fine
use absolute position for the image

```
.navbar{
    position:relative;
}
img{
    position: absolute;
    top:5px;
    right:5px;
    display block;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions

**Best way**

```
.navbarcn{
  background: url('path to your image')
}
```

**Alternative way**

```
.navbar img{
  height: 35px
}
.navbarcn{
  margin-top: -35px
}
```