# Why use :before pseudo-elements to display glyph icons?

Tags: css, glyph

This question is haunting in my brain for a long time. Seem like all glyph icon libraries provide icon by this way, such as [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/). Is this the only way to put glyph in css? or is this the best way?

```
a:before {
   font-family: FontAwesome;
   content: "\f095";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel this question can be divided into two separate ones:

1. Why use fonts for icons?
2. Why use :before pseudo-elements to display them?

For the first part, [reasons are many](https://css-tricks.com/examples/IconFont/), but it boils down to being easy to work with (as they are vectors, have transparent backgrounds by nature, can change colours easily) and had very good support even on older browsers.

For the second part, using pseudo-elements means that your icons can fully "live" in your CSS file. Apart from it being easier to edit there, that's also where they belong - they are not part of your content, but are rather something that affects the appearance of it and thus shouldn't be in your HTML. Think of it as the [same distinction as between img tag and background-image CSS property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492809/when-to-use-img-vs-css-background-image) (once again - design vs content).

In addition, this prevents some strange side-effects, for example, pseudo-elements can't be selected and thus can't be copied. If this weren't the case, all icons would, when copied, result in strange characters in the destination where you copy them.

Comment: Thanks. My question is the second one.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use them as 'i' tags. we can apply much more creative css that way. Here's a codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gLdYqj

```
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/2d1d8af5b4.js"></script>
<div><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>


div{
  font-size:50px;
}
i{
  color:blue;
}
i:hover{
  color:red;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```