# Getting images inline and responsive with a text over the top

Tags: html, css, image, text, css-position

I am trying to get three images in a line within a `div` without spaces and have text display over each of the images that will click through to a different page. I understand the solution to this probably lies in the position of both elements but I cannot seem to get the text to stay over the correct image. If someone could help me with this that would be great?

Below is the HTML.

```
 <div class="services">
            <div id="text-overlay">
                <img src="Untitled-5.jpg">
                <p>Landscaping</p>
            </div>
            <div id="text-overlay">
               <img src="Untitled-6.jpg">
            </div>
            <div id="text-overlay">
                <img src="Untitled-7.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#text-overlay {
    position: relative;
}

img {
    display: block;
    width: 33.3333333333%;
    float: left;
    height: 250px;
}

#text-overlay p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1%;
    left: 1%;
    background-color: firebrick;
    color: white;
    padding: 1%;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Is this the best way to do it or are there better alternatives?

Comment: you should use image as a background of your div

Comment: Start by learning basics such as the fact that IDs have to be _unique_ within an HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has few errors:First of all you should use unique `ID` for indivisual element.Secondly you should use `background-image` for these conditions.Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492809/when-to-use-img-vs-css-background-image) for more details.

If you want to overlay over image learn from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_overlay.asp).