# what is faster? background-image or image

Tags: javascript, html, css, server

My only question is what is faster for the browser to render?

An image as a `background-image` or the same image as a simple `<img src=".">`

Comment: What you need actually ?

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492809/when-to-use-img-vs-css-background-image?rq=1

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ  i had an issue with touch device performances. Simply I don't want the browser to repaint/reflow the whole content becouse when the user scrolls, she/he can see the blank page background.