# why is my background image not working in html5?

Tags: css, html

```
<style>  
background-image: url(".....");  
</style>
```

The background tends to be blank when I use this snippet.Is there any other way to get background image for my page ?.

Comment: Can you write the html code and its proper style code?

Comment: As in your example , you forget to add class name or id name .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use IMG vs. CSS background-image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492809/when-to-use-img-vs-css-background-image)

Answer (score 0):

> The background tends to be blank when i use this snippet

1. That's because you haven't specified the tag in which you want to
   apply the background image to.
2. you haven't specified a valid path to the image.

Simply do something like below but of course replace the URL with your own:

```
body {
    background-image: url("paper.gif");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which element you want to give the background.

Either you give the element a `class` or a `id` or something like `body`.

```css
.class {
    background-image: url("http://icons.veryicon.com/ico/System/Icons8%20Metro%20Style/Logos%20Wikipedia.ico");
}

#id {
    background-image: url("http://icons.veryicon.com/ico/System/Icons8%20Metro%20Style/Logos%20Wikipedia.ico");
}

body {
    background-image: url("https://www.wikipedia.org/portal/wikipedia.org/assets/img/Wikipedia-logo-v2.png");
}
```

```html
<div id="id">Test1</div>
<div class="class">Test2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can write it inline

```
<body style="background-image: url('img/bg.jpg')">
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to specify the `tag, class, or id` you want the `background-image` to be in. Example

   `body, .class, #id {
        background-image: url("img.png");
    }`

or inline-style

```
<div style="background-image: url('something.gif')"></div>
```

2. You also need to be sure of the image path of the image you want to put

for instance if image is in the same folder as `css` or `html` say

```
body {
    background-image: url("image.png");
}
```

if in a folder outside the css folder

```
body {
    background-image: url("../foldername/image.png");
}
```

and so on