# Google chrome image height resize issue

Tags: html, css

Browser goggles chrome for resizing the window height of the images badly scales. Red and green are the same height, you change the window size, red is lower than green. Probllem only occurs in google chrome.

```css
.strona {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.main1,
.main2,
.main3 {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1080px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.cell img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="strona">
  <div class="main1">
    <div class="cell">
      <img src="http://www.glosler.com/test/chrome/img_01.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <img src="http://www.glosler.com/test/chrome/img_02.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main2">
    <div class="cell">
      <img src="http://www.glosler.com/test/chrome/img_03.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <img src="http://www.glosler.com/test/chrome/img_04.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/s6kpzk41/)

[image]

Comment: Tried the fiddle, works fine for me when I resize the result window

Comment: The chrome does't work well [img](http://imgur.com/a/ZBrby)

Comment: If you're gonna use `display: table`, it would be better if you use `<table>` instead, unless you have specific reason for using `display:table`

Answer (score 1):

Although in situation as yours you should use `background-image`rather then `img`.[Why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492809/when-to-use-img-vs-css-background-image).But if you want to use img then
you need to add `min-height:100%` to `.cell img`.

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/shubham_agr10/dkx364b8/)

Here is the code.

```css
.strona {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.main1,
.main2,
.main3 {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1080px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.cell img {
  display: block;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="strona">
  <div class="main1">
    <div class="cell">
      <img src="http://www.glosler.com/test/chrome/img_01.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <img src="http://www.glosler.com/test/chrome/img_02.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main2">
    <div class="cell">
      <img src="http://www.glosler.com/test/chrome/img_03.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <img src="http://www.glosler.com/test/chrome/img_04.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you referring to width not decreasing.If that is the issue then change min-width:100% in img to width:100%;