# What method to use to display background on my site?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, background

I want to integrate the following background on all the pages of my site :

https://www.svgbackgrounds.com/#endless-constellation

There are several methods to do this. Embed the svg code into css, embed the svg code in html, save to an svg file, ...

Which method should I use? What is good practice ?

Comment: you should read this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492809/when-to-use-img-vs-css-background-image hope it helps!

Comment: Have you checked the "HOW TO USE" link on that site? https://www.svgbackgrounds.com/demo/

Comment: When the code is included in html, we can animate it with the css or js

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a background I'd suggest you include it in your CSS.

Comment: Agreed, if it can be done with css I see no reason to add an SVG

Comment: For the record adding SVG into CSS has the advantage of being reusable where as inline SVG is easier to with CSS ( you don't need to create a new dataURI). 

In your case I agree CSS would be the cleanest solution.