# How to keep elements relative to a specific point in a background-image?

Tags: html, css

I got a `background image` of a big white square, and now I'm trying to keep a `div` positioned in the corner of that square, but when I resize the page, that div doesn't follow that corner. I suppose that occurs because of the `background-size: cover;`, since that condition keeps zooming in/out when resized.

I also would like to keep that square in the proportion of the white square.

*background-image and div in normal size*:
[image: background-image and div in normal size]

*resized background-image and div*:
[image]

I'm already using `position: absolute;` and `relative`.

I've been trying to use only flexible values (`vh`, `vw`, `%`)

```css
  .bg {
  background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/3b/6a/ed/3b6aede10e30d93886268de33d67039e.jpg");
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.el {
  width: 5%;
  height: 5%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 13.8%;
  top: 28.5%;
  background: orange;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding:
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="el"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that the image you are using as the background is not only a "black square" since it has white paddings.

If you want everything to align in the box, you either need to:

1. calculate how much the image has paddings before the box (I don't recommend doing).
2. crop the image a bit, removing the white padding.

Here are the calculations after getting rid of the white paddings, and leaving just the borders. You can mess around with the `width`, `height`, `left`, and `top` for more desired results.

```css
.bg {
  background-image: url("bg.jpg");
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vh;
  position: relative;
  margin: 25vh 25vw;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: initial;
  background-size: cover;
}

/* Calculating the "borders" of the image out of the width and height, in this case 1.7% * 2 */
.el {
  width: calc(100% - 3.4%);
  height: calc(100% - 3.4%);
  position: absolute;
  left: 1.7%;
  top: 1.7%;
  background: orange;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

My image has a little bit of white at the bottom, since I cropped the picture a bit badly. Your element `width` & `height` ratio should always be `1:1`, if you want the `.el` to work.

Also, if the purpose is just to make a box with black borders, you might want to do it with just `HTML` and `CSS`, since it's definitely more complex using background images

[image: Here are the results after cropping the paddings and applying the new code]

Comment: I have [edited your code](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71803795/revisions). I removed the run code option because you just provided CSS and run code does not work.

Comment: Thats cool, I do understand your explanation, but now I really don't know how I could apply this same result for a different image. In a different code, I'm using a draw (1920 x 1440) as background-image, and that draw have some lamps in it. My objective was implement a kind of light using a div with a transparent color, but when I resize the page the "light div" breaks his positioning. It's not a white-border question anymore.

Comment: I think that maybe i'm gonna need to use <img> tag instead of the background-image property, because the content is gonna interact with the image. I just read about the difference between these two [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492809/when-to-use-img-vs-css-background-image).