# Website Logo use html img tag or background-image?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a website for practice purposes and I noticed that I have an IMG tag on every html subpage for the website logo.
My question is would it be smarter to assign a background image in css or rather leave the img?

```
<div id="logo_wrapper">
  <a href="/index.html"><img src="./src/img/LOGO Körnig.png" alt="Körni-Logo"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Rather than worry about performance, or looking neat codewise, consider the user, especially one using some sort of assistive technology. Is it important that they are informed of the presence of the image with its alt text being read out to them perhaps or is it there for visual enhancement only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise you to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/492809/10113522). I don't believe that there's any particular impact on performance for this specific use-case. I imagine you're working with static HTML (one HTML file for each page). In this case, every page will either need to load the image separately whenever you load that specific page, or load your CSS file which then references the image in the `background-image` property, hence leading to individual loads of the image per HTML page.

So, in the end, I don't think there's any difference in performance. If you're interested in reducing code repetition, using `background-image` on a single CSS file and including it in every page may be smarter, but there are other considerations when deciding whether to use `<image />` or `background-image` as you can see in the question I linked above.